# Is there a way to make my webapp hosted on streamlit continuously active?

Tags: web, streamlit

I recently deployed an application made with streamlit and after about 2 weeks, when I went to the link again, it looked like this image:

[image]

I had to activate it again, but I would like to know if there is a way to make it active continuously because it will be a site for scientific dissemination. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with streamlit, but it seems like the site goes to sleep in 7 days:
https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/manage-your-app#app-hibernation.

They have recommended some solutions, one of which is **creating some activity.**
You will need to do the following:

> Tell the computer to do a GET request on your website every 7 days in the background to generate traffic and prevent your app from going to sleep.

##### *NIX

To do this you could run a weekly *cronjob* that just does a get request.

To do so:

1. Run `crontab -e` from the terminal
2. Add this:`0 0 * * 0 'curl <urlofwebsite>'`

##### Windows

<s>I am not comfortable with batch/poweshell scripts on windows or automatic scheduling, so you would have to do a bit of research yourself, but the concept is the same.</s>

Powershell Script: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '<urlofwebsite>'`.

I Found this: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7. This can guide you through setting up a routine automation.

Feel free to comment to ask for clarification.